# Getting a file input without label

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a `FileSelector` component which includes a file input which doesn't have a label. I am writing unit tests for that component and I am trying to query this file input but `getByLabelText` won't work because of the lack of label. I have tried `getByRole('input');` but it doesn't work either. I am trying to avoid adding a `data-testid` attribute because there can be more than one of these on the page.

I am going through the docs and GitHub posts but I cannot find a single thread related to an input without a label.

Comment: How come you can't add a `aria-label`? And how come `getByRole('input')` doesn't work?

Comment: I have no idea but using `debug()` function I could see the input but `getByRole('input')` did not find it. I can't add `aria-label` because there is no label.

Comment: Is this a custom made component or a library? Because you can add the ability to put on aria attributes if it's custom. If it's a library I would see if they allow aria attribute props to be passed in.